# What is the regular languages that are equivalent to the given regular language: (0 + 1)*1(0 + 1)*

Tags: regular-language

I am learning automata theory. I have answered the question wrongly three times, and I don't know the right answers. Please help me.

The target language is `(0+1)*1(0+1)*`. The choices are:

```
A) (01+11)*(0+1)*
B) (0+1)*(10+11+1)(0+1)*
C) (1+0)*1(1+0)*
D) (0+1)*(0+1)(0+1)*
```

Multiple choices are allowed, if there's more than one equivalent language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Do you know what the `()`, `*`, and `+` mean? That's the key to this exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Consider your options, and either factor them into a form that looks like your target, or find a word that is in one language but not the other:

Target: `(0+1)*1(0+1)*`, this is the language of all words over `{0,1}` containing at least one `1`.

A) `(01+11)*(0+1)*`, this does not require at least one `1`. For example, the empty string is in A but not in the target.

B) `(0+1)*(10+11+1)(0+1)*`, looking specifically at the `10+11+1` part, which can be factored into `1(0+1+ε)`. `(0+1+ε)(0+1)*` is not different from `(0+1)*`.

C) `(1+0)*1(1+0)*`, this is just the target with `0+1` replaced with `1+0`. The union operation `+` is commutative.

D) `(0+1)*(0+1)(0+1)*`, this language includes the word `0` which is not in the target.

Comment: I have a question for A), We know that (01+11)* includes the empty ”” and (0+1)* includes “1”.  After concatenation “” and “1” makes “1”. So A) includes “1” as well. Where did I go wrong? @Welbog

Comment: Proving that A has a given word in it that the target contains doesn't demonstrate anything interesting. Same as proving that both A and the target do not contain a given word. What's important is finding a word that is in A but not in the target, such as the empty string, or a word that is in the target but not in A (which is nothing, because in this case A is a superset of the target - A is `(0+1)*`). @GayalKuruppu

Comment: I expect your confusion was with my loose use of the term "include". I meant "require", and have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah got your point now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is B & C:

The given regular expression requires every string have at least one 1, with any combination of digits preceding or following the 1. Thus, the first and fourth options are ruled out, as both of these accept the string "0". The second option is equivalent because the middle term "(10 + 11 + 1)" guarantees there is a 1 in the string, and in fact this expression could be replaced by "1" without affecting the language. The third option is equivalent because "+" is commutative and "(0 + 1)" can be replaced by "(1 + 0)".

Answer (score 0):

Given regular language

```
(0+1)*1(0+1)*
```

produces the strings that contains the symbol '1' atleast once.

The every string that can be produced by given language have to be 0 or more 0's or 1's before and after of '1' in the string.

***Option B and C are correct.***

In option B i.e. `(0+1)*(10+11+1)(0+1)*` the middle term i.e. (10+11+1) can produce 1 as like the given regular language in question without affecting the language. So option B can truly produces all strings that can be produced by the given regular language.

**So option B is correct.**

It is clear that the option C i.e. `(1+0)*1(1+0)*` truly produces all the strings that can be produced by the given language in question because '+'  is commutative i.e.(0+1) and (1+0) both produces either 0 or 1.
So option C i.e. `(1+0)*1(1+0)*` is equal to  `(0+1)*1(0+1)*`

**So option C is also correct.**